# ¿Cómo crear una propiedad de sólo lectura en una clase en PHP?

Tags: php, poo

En el siguiente ejemplo se puede ver como crear una propiedad pública, esto me permitiría leer y escribir la variable, pero deseo que solo se pueda leer.

```
<?php
class Test{
    public $luckNumber = 51;
}

$obj = new Test();

//No debe ser posible asignar a esta propiedad
$obj->luckNumber = 42;

echo $obj->luckNumber; //51
```

Comment: rray, creo que deberías elaborar un poco mejor la pregunta para entender qué intentas conseguir. Al leerla, pensé "[cómo crear una constante en PHP?"](http://php.net/manual/es/language.constants.php). Genial por incluir el snippet, pero podrías incluir una explicación más detallada de lo que necesitas?

Comment: Así es, si la "variable" se va a establecer en el código y no durante la ejecución de tu script, podría ser mejor con una constante: `const CONSTANTE = 'valor constante';`

Answer (score 12):

Puedes crear una propiedad de sólo lectura de dos maneras:

**1) Usando los modificadores de acceso**

Cambia el acceso de público a privado y crea un método que devuelva el valor de la propiedad.

Ejemplo:

```
class Test{
    private $luckNumber = 51;

    public function getLuckNumber(){
        return $this->luckNumber;
    }
}

$t = new Test();
echo $t->getLuckNumber(); //51
```

**2) Usando el método `__set()`**

Cambia el acceso de público a privado e implementa el método `__set()`, en el que se hará una comprobación si la propiedad es reescrita y se devolverá un error/lanzará una excepción si es de sólo lectura.

Ejemplo:

```
class Test{
    private $luckNumber = 51;

    public function __set($name, $value){
        if($name == 'luckNumber'){
            trigger_error("can't write a ready only property", E_USER_ERROR );
            //throw new Exception('wow');
        }
    }
}

$t = new Test();

$t->luckNumber = 42; //error
echo $t->luckNumber; //51
```

Más información sobre este método en [PHP - __set() & magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php).

Comment: Hola rray, recuerda que este es un sitio en **español**, por otro lado, si estas es una pregunta/respuesta migrada de SO, no olvides poner las referencias respectivas a sus autores originales. Con respecto a la respuesta lo que estamos haciendo es ponerla como wiki de comunidad

Comment: En el segundo método, `luckNumber` es privada de por sí y no se puede modificar ni acceder desde fuera (es una variante del primer método), lo único que se está haciendo con el `__set()` es reescribir el mensaje de error. Por eso `echo $t->luckNumber; //51` seguirá lanzando una excepción/error porque se está intentando acceder a una variable privada. Habría que definir también el método `__get()`

Answer (score 4):

Puedes hacer que la variable sea privada con el modificador `private`, tal y como se ha dicho en [otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/611/143). De esta forma la variable **no** podrá ser modificada desde fuera de la clase que la contiene, pero **sí** desde el interior de dicha clase.

La forma de conseguir verdaderamente una "variable de sólo lectura" cuyo valor no pueda ser modificado desde ningún sitio, es simplemente no usar una *variable*, sino definir una [*constante*](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.constants.php):

```
class Test
{
    const LUCK_NUMBER = 51;
}

echo Test::LUCK_NUMBER; // Imprime 51

Test::LUCK_NUMBER = 42; // Error de compilación, expresión no asignable
```

Answer (score 2):

La forma elegante es usar los métodos mágicos __get y __set  ( no abuses de ellos porque hacen más lenta la ejecución ). Puedes incluso crear propiedades calculadas

un ejemplo:

```
<?php

class Test{
    private $alto   =    4;
    private $ancho  =  5;

public function __set( $nombre, $valor ){
    switch( $nombre )
    {
        case 'alto':
        {
            $this->alto = $valor;
            break;
        }
        case 'ancho':
        {
            $this->ancho = $valor;
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            echo $nombre, " es de solo lectura\n";
        }
    }
}

public function __get( $nombre ){
    switch( $nombre )
    {
        case 'alto':
        {
            return $this->alto;
        }
        case 'ancho':
        {
            return $this->ancho;
        }
        case 'superficie':
        {
            return $this->ancho * $this->alto;
        }

    }
}
}

$t = new Test();
echo 'superficie ', $t->superficie, "\n";    
$t->alto = 23;
$t->ancho = 12;

echo 'alto ', $t->alto, "\n";
echo 'ancho ', $t->ancho, "\n";
echo 'superficie ', $t->superficie, "\n";
$t->superficie = 12;
echo 'superficie ', $t->superficie, "\n";
```

la salida es:

superficie 20

alto 23

ancho 12

superficie 276

superficie es de solo lectura

superficie 276

Answer (score 1):

Es simple :

```
class Test{
    public $luckNumber = 51;
}
```

#### Por protected

Una variable se puede definir como :

1. public (publica) , se puede acceder desde cualquier sitio o clase
   que instancie la clase en la que se encuentra :

   ```
   $clase = new Test();
   $clase->luckNumber = 0;
   ```
2. private (privada) , no se puede acceder.
3. Elemento de lista protected (protegida) , es como si fuera publica pero sin poderse modificar.

   ```
   class Test{ 
    protected $luckNumber = 51;
   }
   ```

#### Por funciones SET y GET

```
class Test{ 
   private $luckNumber = 51;
   public function getLuckNumber(){
    return $this->luckNumber;
   }
}
...
$clase = new Test();
$valor = $clase->getLuckNumber();
```